# Search going to /index.php?q= instead of results

Tags: entries, search, routes

I've pushed my site to Digital Ocean from Localhost, the site is all up and running - URL's are all working. But when I try and search the site it seems to be heading to

> http://123.456.789/index.php?q=test

Instead of

> http://123.456.789/search/results?q=ariz

I have manually entered the second page in and I get to the search results page, so it does exist but Craft's routes seem to be breaking? Any help would be brilliant!

```
        <form action="{{ url('search/results') }}">
          <input class="text-field w-input" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search for any University...">
          <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" tabindex="-1" />
        </form>
```

Comment: What does your form code look like? It sounds like the test URL might be hardcoded.

Comment: Added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the typical '/' within the URL

The correct URL for this path should be:

> {{ url('/search/results') }}